# JPA not returning the records which contain empty columns in the EmbeddedId

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

JpaRepository's `findAll()` method does not return the rows, if any of the field in the composite key is null.

This is the entity class with the *EmbeddedId* `JobVaccinationPK`

```
/**
 * ApplicationParam entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="job_vaccination",schema="cdcis")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JobVaccination  implements java.io.Serializable {


    // Fields    
     @Column(name="default_yn", length=1)
     private String defaultYn;

     @EmbeddedId
     private JobVaccinationPK jobVaccinationPK;

     public JobVaccination(){

     }

     //setters getters
}
```

This is the Embedded class

```
@Embeddable
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JobVaccinationPK implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("job_category_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_category_id", nullable=true)
    private JobCategoryTypeMast jobCategoryMast;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("vaccination_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "vaccination_id",   nullable=true)
    private VaccinationMast vaccinationMast;


    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("screening_type_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "screening_type_id",  nullable=true)
    private ScreeningTypeMast screeningTypeMast;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Service implementation class

```
@Override
    public SearchResult<JobVaccinationDto> getJobVaccination(JobVaccinationDto dto)
            throws VaccinationException {

        List<JobVaccination> vaccDetails = jobVaccinationRepo.findAll();
        if(vaccDetails == null) return null;
        List<JobVaccinationDto> jobVaccinationDtos = new ArrayList<JobVaccinationDto>();
        jobVaccinationDtos = convertToDto(vaccDetails);
        return new SearchResult<>(jobVaccinationDtos.size(), jobVaccinationDtos);

}
```

Here am able to insert a null value for either `jobCategoryId` or `screeningTypeId`, just like below row. But when I'm trying to fetch the rows which have empty values, it returns null. I've tried to debug but I was not able to find the cause.

[image]

This is the generated hibernate query:

```
 Hibernate: 
        select
            jobvaccina0_.job_category_id as job_cate4_13_,
            jobvaccina0_.screening_type_id as screenin2_13_,
            jobvaccina0_.vaccination_id as vaccinat3_13_,
            jobvaccina0_.default_yn as default_1_13_ 
        from
            cdcis.job_vaccination jobvaccina0_
    Hibernate: 
        select
            jobcategor0_.job_category_id as job_cate1_11_0_,
            jobcategor0_.job_category_name as job_cate2_11_0_,
            jobcategor0_.job_category_name_ar as job_cate3_11_0_,
            jobcategor0_.screening_type_id as screenin4_11_0_ 
        from
            cdcis.job_category_mast jobcategor0_ 
        where
            jobcategor0_.job_category_id=?
    Hibernate: 
        select
            screeningt0_.screening_type_id as screenin1_21_0_,
            screeningt0_.active_yn as active_y2_21_0_,
            screeningt0_.mmpid_required_yn as mmpid_re3_21_0_,
            screeningt0_.screening_type as screenin4_21_0_ 
        from
            cdcis.screening_type_mast screeningt0_ 
        where
            screeningt0_.screening_type_id=?
    Hibernate: 
        select
            vaccinatio0_.vaccination_id as vaccinat1_27_0_,
            vaccinatio0_.vaccination_name as vaccinat2_27_0_,
            vaccinatio0_.vaccination_name_ar as vaccinat3_27_0_ 
        from
            cdcis.vaccination_mast vaccinatio0_ 
        where
            vaccinatio0_.vaccination_id=?
```

Going with @Adam Michalik answer. As a work-around I've introduced a new primary key field in the table, as we can't handle a null in the composite key.

[image]

Comment: so you looked at the SQL invoked to get the objects from the DB then?

Comment: @ Neil Stockton: Its a select query to fetch all the data without any where condition. Updated the question with query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composite IDs cannot contain null values in any of the fields. Since the SQL semantics of `NULL` is that `NULL <> NULL`, it cannot be determined that a primary key `(1, 2, NULL)` is equal to `(1, 2, NULL)`.

`NULL` means "no value" in SQL and its interpretation is up to you on a case-by-case basis. That's why SQL and JPA do not want to make assumptions that `NULL = NULL` and that a primary key containing a `NULL` identifies a single entity only.

You may choose to use a synthetic, generated primary key instead of the composite business primary key to overcome that. Then, you'd always have a non-null, single-column PK and nullable foreign keys.

Comment: Not sure how the save is working. Now resolved the problem by introducing a new primary key for the table. updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

change the data type of particular row in entity from int to integer

Comment: Please provide a more complete answer, including example code if possible.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear. As others already pointed out, you should exand your answer with more details and add some sample code based on the one posted by the OP, if possible.